# Import many query results in the same sheet csv file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have three queries :

```
select count(*) from facttable;

Select distinct customerkey from facttable;

select distinct productkey from facttable;
```

I need to put the result of these three queries in the same sheet in a csv file using SSIS,

the Output will be :

Number of lines : 100(just example) 
List of customerid : 12ff

15kif 
List of product id : mokd125

oki89

How to put results in the same csv sheet ?

Comment: that's not a csv, but a text file and I would use C# and a string builder

Comment: I have a new idea since it is only one column. I'll post answer.

Comment: The senior user need to visualise the result as tables in csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your extract query to this:

```
select 'Number of records: ' + cast(count(*) as varchar(50)) as data from facttable

union all select ''
union all select 'List of Customer ID:'
union all
Select distinct cast(customerkey as varchar(50)) from facttable;
union all select ''
union all select 'List of Product ID:'
union all
select distinct cast(productkey as varchar(50)) from facttable;
```

This will give you a one column data set that can be written out to a text file.

UNION ALL is critical here as it takes ALL records. UNION gets rid of duplicates.